# Wie den uneindeutigen Superlativ von "nahe", eindeutig machen?

Tags: ambiguity, clarification

> Sei x = 4,2, was ist die nächste natürliche Zahl?

Da »nächste« nicht zwischen räumlicher/absoluter Distanz (am wenigsten weit entfernt) und zeitlich/sequentieller Abfolge (unmittelbar folgend) unterscheidet ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/naechste)), kann sowohl 4 als auch 5 als richtige Lösung angesehen werden. Im Englischen bspw. gibt es diese Unterscheidung:

> Let x = 4.2, what is the *next* natural number? 5.
>
> Let x = 4.2, what is the *nearest* natural number? 4.

U.a. [hier](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2011/11/30/die-naechste-tankstelle/) wird diskutiert die räumliche/absolute Distanz/Nähe mit *am nähesten* zu bezeichnen. Solange das aber noch allgemein als Fehler angesehen wird, wie kann ich obige Frage eindeutig stellen?
Wenn ich auf absolute Distanz hinaus will würde sich folgendes anbieten:

> Sei x = 4,2, was ist die nächste natürliche Zahl *zu x*?

bei Abfolge auf dem Zahlenstrahl:

> Sei x = 4,2, was ist die nächste natürliche Zahl *nach x*?

Aber ist das eindeutig?

Comment: In Kontinentaleuropa, und somit überall wo Deutsch gesprochen wird, ist das Dezimaltrennzeichen kein Punkt (4.2) sondern ein Komma (4,2). Ich habe das in deiner Frage entsprechend korrigiert.

Comment: Hm. Eigentlich ist die Frage fü *x* = 4,2 eindeutig. Da 4,2 selbst keine natürliche Zahl ist, kann man auch nicht nach der _nächsten_ natürlichen Zahl, also im Sinne der ihr _nachfolgenden_ natürlichen Zahl fragen. Demnach kann mit _nächste_ nur die in kürzestem Abstand liegende natürliche Zahl gemeint sein. Anders wäre die Sache für *x* = 4.

Comment: Gute Frage. Man sollte den Superlativ zu "naheste" oder "näheste" ändern :-)

Comment: @Marco13: At least in spoken German, "näheste" is already quite common.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Vom detektivischen Standpunkt aus betrachtet kann ich Deiner Argumentation folgen, aber in der Mathematik ist es üblich an einen Zahlenstrahl zu denken, der aus dem Ursprung heraus führt, und nach der 4,2 kommt als nächste ganze Zahl dann doch die 5. Als Trickfrage, die mit der Uneindeutigkeit spielt, ist sie im Deutschunterricht passend, im Matheunterricht ist sie aber deplaziert. Das Alter, in dem die Frage bei richtiger Interpretation schwer zu beantworten ist, dürfte eins sein, in dem die Schüler Mathematikersprache noch kaum verinnerlicht haben und der Willkür …

Comment: … des Lehrers bei der Festlegung, welche Interpretation richtig ist, auf unfaire Weise unterlegen sind. Erwachsene scheitern oft bei der Identifikation des Datums für nächsten Samstag, den sie mit dem Samstag nächster Woche verwechseln. Von Köln nach Berlin fahrend darf ich aber auch in Wuppertal nach der nächsten Millionenstadt fragen - ist das jetzt Köln oder Berlin?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich ist für viele der nächste Mittwoch auch gestern. :)

Comment: @userunknown Wenn du auf deiner Strecke Köln -> Berlin durch Braunschweig oder Göttingen kommst, ist die nächste (als näheste) Millionenstadt etwas ganz neues: Hamburg. Das Datumsbeispiel (dieser, kommende, nächster Samstag) zeigt auch, das "nächster" unklar im Gebrauch ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei der Formulierung

> Sei x = 4.2, was ist die nächste natürliche Zahl *zu x*?

könnte man immernoch annehmen, dass die nächst*größere* Zahl gemeint ist. Das kleine Wort "zu" ist in diesem Sinne nicht "mathematisch streng" definiert. Ein pedantischer Mathematiker würde diese Uneindeutigkeit vielleicht bemerken und gezielt nachfragen. Aber man könnte das auch einfach verstehen als *"in bezug auf x"* oder *"für x"*.

Eine Möglichkeit könnte sein, von der *nächstgelegenen* Zahl zu reden. Damit ist klarer, dass die "Position" der Zahl auf dem Zahlenstrahl gemeint ist, und es wirklich um die Zahl geht, die die geringste (absolute) Differenz zur gegebenen Zahl hat.

> Sei x = 4.2, was ist die nächstgelegene natürliche Zahl zu x?

Um sicher zu sein kann man aber genau das auch so schreiben:

> Sei x = 4.2, was ist die natürliche Zahl, die zu x die geringste absolute Differenz hat?

<sub>Ja, es ist schade, dass man das nicht ähnlich kurz und präzise formulieren kann, wie mit "nearest" im Englischen.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Das macht man typischerweise mit

> nächstliegend

oder

> am nächsten liegend

wenn man nicht möchte, dass "nächste" mit "nächste in auf/absteigender Reihenfolge" verwechselt werden kann.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn du das eindeutig haben willst, musst du es anders formulieren:

> Sei x = 4,2: Welche natürliche Zahl hat den geringsten Abstand zu x?

Answer (score 1):

Um die beiden Fälle klar zu unterscheiden, würde ich Folgendes vorschlagen:

> Sei x = 4,2. Welche natürliche Zahl liegt x am nächsten?

4

> Sei x = 4,2. Was ist die erste natürliche Zahl, die größer als x ist?

5

Comment: Anstatt "die erste" würde ich "die kleinste" schreiben.

Comment: @CarstenS: _»die erste«_ ist nicht weniger eindeutig.

Comment: "die erste" - die dir einfällt, die du würfeln wirst, die du im Telefonbuch findest? Für eine Prüfungsaufgabe wäre diese Formulierung nicht geeignet.

Comment: Pollitzer hat aber "die erste, die größer als x ist" geschrieben, nicht "die erste, die Dir einfällt".

Answer (score 1):

Man könnte auch zur Unterscheidung, wenn man auf 5 hinaus will,

> Sei x = 4.2, was ist die *nächsthöhere* natürliche Zahl zu x?

fragen, das ist gar nicht so unüblich.
Das Pendant dazu (auf die 4 zielend) hat bereits Marco13 in seiner Antwort aufgelistet:

> Sei x = 4.2, was ist die *nächstgelegene* natürliche Zahl zu x?